# What is the default password in Sitecore 9?

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Recently I installed Sitecore 9.0 version in my system and after successful installation I tried with Sitecore default credentials (admin/b) but it was not working.

But I remember that during Sitecore training the tutor taught me that the default one is "**admin/b**"

This doesn't seem to work on Sitecore 9.

Is there any way to configure the password during installation?

Comment: Correct, the default password is not "b" as you state. The "SIF-Default" tells the script to generate a new password. Once the installation is complete, the output log file tells you the Sitecore Admin password. I would imagine the password was changed to be more secure and avoid accidentally going to production with "b" as the password.

Comment: @MichaelWest, Thanks for the clarification. So sitecore default password is not "b" anymore

Comment: Correct. The default password is either auto-generated or whatever you make it in the SIF configuration used when installing Sitecore.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your clarification, @MichaelWest

Comment: The default password for Sitecore 9.0 is still **admin/b**. The default password for Sitecore 9.1 is as Michael West states, set in the SIF script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When installing Sitecore 9 (using SIF) you execute a powershell script called `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` (at least for installing a Single On Premises instance). In this file you should find a line that looks like this:

```
$SitecoreAdminPassword = "SIF-Default"
```

That line determines the password used for the `admin` user. Change this to whatever you want, and after the installation is completed you can log on as *admin* using that password (you can even set the password to "b" if you want to).

As per the installation documentation:

> [...] edit the `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` script and update each line with the settings that are appropriate for your environment. One of the settings that you must edit is `SitecoreAdminPassword`.
>
> If you do not specify the Sitecore administrator password in the script and leave the example value "SIF-Default" unchanged, a random password is generated for you. This password is written to the `XP0-SingleDeveloper.log` file – search for *Sitecore Admin Password* – and displayed when the `sitecore-xp0.json` file has been processed

Answer (score 0):

There is a SetSitecoreAdminPassword.sql file is available in installation zip file. This sql script talks about admin password generation. Please check the below

declare @ApplicationName nvarchar(256) = 'sitecore'
declare @UserName nvarchar(256) = 'sitecore\admin'
declare @Password nvarchar(128) = 'PlaceHolderForPassword'
declare @HashAlgorithm nvarchar(10) = 'SHA1'
declare @PasswordFormat int = 1 -- Hashed
declare @CurrentTimeUtc datetime = SYSUTCDATETIME()
declare @Salt varbinary(16) = 0x
declare @HashedPassword varbinary(20)
declare @EncodedHash nvarchar(128)
declare @EncodedSalt nvarchar(128)

-- Generate random salt
while len(@Salt) < 16
begin
    set @Salt = (@Salt + cast(cast(floor(rand() * 256) as tinyint) as binary(1)))
end

**-- Hash password
set @HashedPassword = HASHBYTES(@HashAlgorithm, @Salt + cast(@Password as varbinary(128)));**

-- Convert hash and salt to BASE64
select @EncodedHash = cast(N'' as xml).value(
                  'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
                , 'varchar(max)'
            ) from (select @HashedPassword as [bin] ) T

select @EncodedSalt = cast(N'' as xml).value(
                  'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
                , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
            ) from (select @Salt as [bin] ) T

Comment: After successful installation, you will be able to find credentials in log file